# Firebase Auth duplicate account when using Google/Facebook in Android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I integrated Firebase authentication in my android app.

I cannot found any way to have a unique account for email address for both google and facebook authentication. It's *either* I receive an error saying there is already an account using this email address if I don't allow "Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address" on Firebase sign in settings, *or* it will create 2 unique UID accounts for each login method with the same email address..

Is there a good workaround for it and manage to have 1 account with unique UID and email address for both facebook and google login methods?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called [account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) in Firebase terms.

In this use-case you first sign in the user with either of these providers, and then link the credentials from the other provider from the same account. So you end up with a single account, with two linked providers.

To find out what providers are linked to an email address (for example to render a UI with the sign-in options for a user), you'll want to call [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thank you, So I have looked into the link you provided and it seems to be a solution for me, but I didnt understand something: If I only enable 1 account per email address and my user login in the first time using Google, so I need to link his google credentials and then if he tries to login with the same email but using facebook provider then it will work because he has credentials already linked to that email in firebase? If so then also how will you handle it for further logins without doing credential linking in every login? is there an option to see if the user already has an account?

Comment: When the user tries to sign in with a second provider, you need to create create credentials for that other provider as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account. You then link those credentials to the original account, and from that moment the user can sign in to the account with either of the linked providers.

Comment: I see but how will I add those credentials to the original account if the account is not signed in? lets say I now signed in using Google, then I sign out and try to sign in again using Facebook, both with the same email address, it throws NullPointerException when I try to do `auth.currentuser.linkWithCredential()` because there is no current user.. what am I missing here in the logic?

Comment: They will need to signed in with their original account. So that's where you'd use `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`, so that you can detect what the user originally signed in with, and ask them to sign in with that again so that you can connect the two providers.